# Replace Swagger UI with Open API 3 Standards - Custom Content

Tags: swagger, webapi

I have Web API project which is created in 4.7.2, due to dependency unable to upgrade to .Net Core but want to use feature of Open API 3 standards.
To do that followed some of the articles to how to replace custom files, but problem is after adding custom `index.html` file, `css and javascripts` files are not loading. if use default `swagger ui`  then `css and javascript` file are working fine.

```
.EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
 {
    // Use the "DocumentTitle" option to change the Document title.
    // Very helpful when you have multiple Swagger pages open, to tell them apart.
    c.DocumentTitle($"Eclipse API {eclipseVersion}");

    c.InjectStylesheet(thisAssembly, "API.Content.Swagger.V3.swagger-ui.css");
    c.InjectStylesheet(thisAssembly, "API.Content.Swagger.V3.index.css");
    c.InjectStylesheet(thisAssembly, "API.Content.EclipseSwagger.css");

    c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly, "API.Content.Swagger.V3.swagger-initializer.js");
    c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly, "API.Content.Swagger.V3.swagger-ui-bundle.js");
    c.InjectJavaScript(thisAssembly, "API.Content.Swagger.V3.swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js");

    c.CustomAsset("index", thisAssembly, "API.Content.Swagger.V3.index.html");
});
```

So, how to use `css and javascripts` files along with custom html file.?
I tried adding files in `wwwroot/swagger/ui` folder also but does not working.
Anything missing here.?

getting `404 Not Found` for added files,

`index.html` file

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Swagger UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./swagger-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>
    <script src="./swagger-ui-bundle.js" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
    <script src="./swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
    <script src="./swagger-initializer.js" charset="UTF-8"> </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and `swagger-initializer.js` file

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    window.ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: getCurrentURL(),
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
        deepLinking: true,
        presets: [
            SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
            SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        plugins: [
            SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
        ],
        layout: "StandaloneLayout"
    });

})

function getCurrentURL() {
    return window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '/api/documentation';
}
```